# How to get all the keys defined in property file in spring framework

Tags: java, spring

I need to get all the keys in a property file and store it into a bean variable.
For example I need something like below

```
abc=df
sad=tyh
```

Then I need to get `{abc,sad}`. All this thing I need to do using spring framework .Is this can be possible (I know probability of getting this type requirement is very less but just need to know is it possible)

Comment: Use `Properties` api: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html

Comment: @FranMontero In java I can use the keySet) method of properties but I'm using spring instead

Comment: I believe Spring does not provide that functionality. Use `Properties.propertyNames()`

Answer (score -1):

you can try try like 
define bean in applicationContext like

```
<bean id="applicationProperties"
        class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertiesFactoryBean">
        <property name="locations">
            <list>
                <value>classpath*:*.properties</value>
                <value>classpath*:*.properties</value>
                <value>classpath*:*.properties</value>
                <value>classpath*:*.properties</value>
                <value>classpath*:*.properties</value>
                <value>classpath*:*.properties</value>
                <value>classpath*:*.properties</value>
                <value>classpath*:*.properties</value>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

and declare like

```
@Resource(name = "applicationProperties")
    private Properties properties;
```

and getProperty like

```
String str = properties.getproperty('keyname');
Enumeration allkeys = properties.propertyNames();
```

Comment: User wants all keys in the properties file. Your solution requires knowing the keys prior.

Comment: try like Enumeration allkeys = properties.propertyNames();

Comment: You could've deleted the completely irrelevant previous answer when you were at it.

Comment: @kryger Not me, I dont have permission to delete answer.

Comment: When editing you can freely remove parts that are not applicable or relevant.

Comment: @ kryger ok i will try.